# CSS: Vertically aligning inline-block element in a line of text

Tags: css

I have an inline-block element put inside a line of text:

[image]

`.icon` element has `vertical-align: middle;`, which results in this picture:

[image]

As you can see, the icon is not aligned with the middle of the text, it is a little bit lower, whilst the text alignment looks OK. The `.button-content` has `line-height` equal to the height of the parent. I tried to wrap the text elements around the icon:

[image]

And got this result:

[image]

The coin went up a little relatively to the text, whereas the whole line went down a pixel or two.

What is the proper way to align an inline-block element inside a lign of text? And what are these text chunks and how do they behave? Do they have `display:inline;` or something, because I can't see their properties in the DevTools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical-align doesn't work like you would think it would. It's used in HTML tables, but doesn't work in divs. It's been a pain for a while. Luckily, nowadays you can achieve this easily with flexbox.

To achieve this, wrap your two bits of copy in individual `span` elements, so your structure looks like:

```
<div class="button-content">
    <span>buy for</span>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <span>1000</span>
</div>
```

Then your css should look like this:

```
.button-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 130px;
}
```

Or if you can't support `flexbox`, your `.button-content` can be set to `display: table-cell;` and the `vertical-align: middle;` should work.

I strongly recommend flexbox.

Comment: `vertical-align` works fine with the pseudo elements `:after` or `:before`, `spans`, `divs`, `tables`, `whatever`. It only doesnt work if the element is larger that the available space (limited by the height/width + padding of the parent). _If the element is larger:_ than `vertical-align` doesn't work like we'd expected. Still, I would not recommend using flexboxes very often. Older mobile devices and browsers don't support it. And unfortunately a lot of people are using these older devices/browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The icon actually IS aligned vertically, but relating to the complete line-height, including the space below the baseline reserved for the descenders of characters like y, g, p etc . (also the y in your button Text)
 You can try to add `position: relative;` and `bottom: 3px;` (try different values) to that inline-block to move it up.

Comment: I can understand this logic of alignment, but I don't understand why it changes when I wrap the text in inline-block elements.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your span elements are styled, the result will be the same with or without them.

With `vertical-align: middle; position: relative; top: -1px;` you can get some nice results.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue
}
.top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.moveup {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <span>Buy for</span>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <span>1000</span>
</div>

<div class="button">
  Buy for
  <div class="icon"></div>
  1000
</div>

<hr>

<div class="button">
  Buy for
  <div class="icon top"></div>
  1000 vertical-align: top;
</div>

<div class="button">
  Buy for
  <div class="icon bottom"></div>
  1000 vertical-align: bottom;
</div>

<div class="button">
  Buy for
  <div class="icon middle"></div>
  1000 vertical-align: middle;
</div>

<hr>

<div class="button">
  Buy for
  <div class="icon middle moveup"></div>
  1000 vertical-align: middle; top: -1px;
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Simple answer

I have not seen a simple answer yet, so I'll just post mine:

```
.icon_tpye-gold {
  vertical-align: -5px; /* << or another value to center the inline element vertically */
}
```

A suggestion: be consistent with class names (so `icon_type-gold` is clearer when named `icon_type_gold` or `icon-type-gold`, this looks less sloppy)

Comment: @Cubius thank you for sharing this! Did not even know this site!